# MVC5 Class in App_Code exists in both temp directories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I have GlobalSettings.cs in App_Code folder and it stores various settings in Session for my application. It works fine in my WebForm project and I copied it to MVC5 project for the same purpose.

I set GlobalSettings.cs Build Action to "Compile" from "Content".  Otherwise, I couldn't even compile the MVC project.

But when I run the page it displays an error like this in my Layout.cshtml.  It keeps saying that it exists in my temps folders.  I tried to delete temp directories, Clear the Build, Rebuild it.  But it's not working.  If I remove that @ITS.GlobalSettings.RefNo code, it works fine with no problem.

[image]

Codes in App_Code\GlobalSettings.cs

```
namespace ITS
{
    public class GlobalSettings
    {

        public static string RefNo
        {
            get
            {
                return (HttpContext.Current.Session["RefNo"] == null) ? string.Empty : HttpContext.Current.Session["RefNo"].ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["RefNo"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You class is missing the **static** modifier in the definition, that's one issue that I can see:

```
public static class GlobalSettings
{
}
```

Do you have a reference to another assembly that contains the same definition?  If so, remove it.